# Iterating over a list with specific rules

Tags: python, list

I'm writing a program that analyzes DHCP packets, and came across option 43 (Vendor Specific Information). This is more of a programming question, and less technically related to networking and DHCP, therefore I tagged it as just python.

According to RFC 2132 (page 19), the structure of option 43 is as follows:

```
 Code   Len   Data item        Code   Len   Data item       Code
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  T1 |  n  |  d1 |  d2 | ... |  T2 |  n  |  D1 |  D2 | ... | ... |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

When translated to a python 'bytes' object, it should look something like this:

```
[T1, n, d1, d2, ..., T2, n, D1, D2, ...]
```

Where n is the length of the data item (Dn).

Ideally, I want to iterate over this bytes object and save the code for each data item as a key, and map it to the appropriate data item value. IE:

```
{T1: [d1, d2, d3], T2: [D1, D2, D3]}
```

For example this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Should translate to this:

```
{0: [2], 1: [5,6], 3: [9, 10, 11, 12]}
```

Is there a correct way to do this in python?

EDIT: Also, yes. Codes (Tn) are unique.

Comment: Are `T1` to `Tn` guaranteed to be unique? if not then you can't store that info in a dictionary.

Comment: Since you know the pattern before hand. This should be fairly simple. Keep counter variables and array copy into dict objects. If you are looking for more idiomatic way, I do not think there is one as this is not a common case scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a recursive function:

```
trans_dict = {}
def translate(lst, trans_dict):
    if(len(lst) == 0):
        return
    else:   ​
        trans_dict[lst[0]] = lst[2:(2+lst[1])]        # the first element will be the key, 
                                                      # the value starts from the third 
                                                      # element with length of the second element
        translate(lst[(2+lst[1]):], trans_dict)

translate(lst, trans_dict)

trans_dict
# {0: [2], 1: [5, 6], 3: [9, 10, 11, 12]}
```

Comment: Upvoted and marked correct because this works and the explanation was easy to understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
packets = [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 12]

pos_head = 0
len_data = len(packets)

d = dict()

while pos_head  < len_data:
    key = packets[pos_head]
    if pos_head +2 > len_data:
        break
    size = packets[pos_head+1]
    if pos_head + 2 + size > len_data:
        break
    data = packets[pos_head+2: pos_head+2 + size]
    pos_head += 2 + size
    d[key] = data

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{0: [2], 1: [5, 6], 3: [9, 10, 11, 12]}
```

**Observation**: T1, T2, ..., Tn should not be repeated.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a `for` loop in combination with an itertor. The outer `for` loop will loop over all the values of `T`, while calls to `next` within the loop remove the `n` and `d1`, ..., `dn` from the list.

```
def parse(data):
    iterator = iter(data)
    d = {}
    for t in iterator:
        n = next(iterator)
        d[t] = [next(iterator) for _ in range(n)]
    return d
```

You could even put all of this into a single dictionary comprehension...

```
def parse(data):
    it = iter(data)
    return {t: [next(it) for _ in range(next(it))] for t in it}
```

Example:

```
>>> data = [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> parse(data)
{0: [2], 1: [5, 6], 3: [9, 10, 11, 12]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using nested `while` and `for` loops, my solution is (`T1` to `Tn` should be unique as they are the resulted dictionary keys):

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 12]

res = {}
i = 0

while i < len(my_list):
    num = my_list[i+1]
    for j in range(i+2, i+2+num):
        if i in res:
            res[i].append(my_list[j])
        else:
            res[i] = [my_list[j]]
    i += 2 + num
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
{0: [2], 3: [5, 6], 7: [9, 10, 11, 12]}
```